# jQuery click does not work in pop-up

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

I have two files that are exact in coding, file A and B. Within File A, there are links to create a popup of File B. At the top of file A, I created a link (a href) that, when clicked, alerts the user. This exact code is in file B. It works in file A, but not in file B.

```
    <a href="#" id="send-email">Send Email</a>
```

And the jQuery:

```
    $('#send-email').click(function(e) {
        alert('works');
    });
```

The curious thing is, they are all linked to the same external jQuery file, and every other jQuery function that is there works (eg, accordion menu), except this popup click. I tried using the jQueryUI first, but that's how I discovered this issue; then I went down to just the barebones click-alert, and that's the code I posted above.

Does .click work in pop-ups? If so, how?

Comment: yes , it will work in a pop-up , open it in a browser and inspect the element of what you're trying to click and find the exact id of the element, the browser may have changed the id

Comment: @ScottSelby if his browser is changing his ID's, I'd suggest he find himself a new browser :)

Comment: Turns out, it was an issue with being within $(document).ready(function()). Am thinking pop-ups aren't considered as being "ready", which is why I was having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pop up is really no different than any other page (except when you get into talking about session state and contexts in certain browsers, but that isn't the issue here). `click` functions the same way in a pop up that it does in any other window. There are lots of things that could be causing your issue, though. Duplicate ID's, missing/misspelled function, etc.

So I can't give you a definitive answer yet, but here's a good step to debug it:

instead of attaching a click event to it the way you're doing it (note that your way is far more correct than my way, but my way aids in debugging), do it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "alert('works')" id="send-email">Send Email</a>
```

If that doesn't work, maybe you're blocking pop-ups or something. It's a problem with the alert. If it DOES work, try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "AlertIt()" id="send-email">Send Email</a>
```

with this elsewhere on your page:

```
function AlertIt() {
alert("worked");
}
```

If this works too, you're more than likely looking at a problem loading jQuery or a jQuery conflict.

Edit: oh, one more thing. Try using jQuery's `live` function. This attaches the event handler to elements whether they exist already or not. `click` will only attach the event if the element already exists. It is possible that this is caused by the order of operations, so to speak, that you're using.

`live` looks like this:

```
$("#send-email").live("click", function(){ alert("Worked"); });
```

Comment: All of these options worked, marking it as correct. I did a test on my old code, and it looks like the issue was that the code was within the $(document).ready(function()). Am going to take an (incorrect?) stab and say that the code worked, except that the problem was the popup wasn't considered as being "ready". Once I moved the code outside of that function, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Hybride well, actually, that's not quite how document.ready() works. The `document.ready(... )` part of it is what is called an event. The `function(){ ... }` part you see inside it is called an event *handler*. Everything inside that function runs when the document's `ready` event is fired, which happens when all of the elements have been loaded. To put it simply, anything you put in the function inside document.ready() waits until all of the elements have finished loading, then executes automatically. Interestingly, the ready handler is actually probably the **best** place for that code.

Comment: @Hybride My updated guess, then, is that you have a jQuery conflict in the context of your ready handler. Or it could be that you have a syntax error near your ready handler, and it isn't being parsed as a function, so it isn't getting called. No matter what, though, something funky is going on in your document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @voigtan. Assigning event-handlers for dynamic content can be tricky.

It might be the case that the event handler is not bound for the content in the popup, in case when you bind events in the document ready handler. There are two ways you could take care of that:

1. Have a callback after the popup content is displayed, and bind the events for new elements
2. If the elements have a uniform event handler, assign them a class which could be used as a selector and attach the events with jQuery::live() call. Here is an example:

   ```
   <a href="#" class="send-email">Send Email</a>

   $(function() {
       $(document).on("click", "a.send-email", function(e) {
           alert('works');
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with pop-ups? is it jQueryUI dialog you mean? if so does the markup exist when you load the javascript code?

you could use `.on` if you are using jQuery 1.7+ and just do a delegate on all `#send-email` that is either on the page when it loads or you load it in dyanmic with AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#send-email", function(e) {
        alert('works');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```